# What does javascript closure on anonymous function mean,and when to use closed anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript

I understand that there are self executable anonymous functions such as:

```
var func = function(){
   return 'hello';
}();
```

And i have seen another version of it with closures.

```
var func = (function(){
   return 'hello';
}());
```

as far as i have tested both syntax delivers same result and has similar behavior.Whats the purpose for having closures? thanks in advance.

Comment: you misunderstood closure, please read it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).And "self executable anonymous functions" has a name IIFE, greatly explained [here](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Answer (score 2):

Lets take ur example and modify little bit.

```
var func = (function(){
   //here are some local variables
   var demo = 'hello'
   return function(){
     return demo;
   }
}());

func() // outputs "hello"
```

here function is executed and it creates its local variable 'demo' with value 'hello' and it returns a function.In java script after function execution its all local variables are **destroyed** or **garbage collected**.But in this special case the returned anonymous function still has **access** to this variable 'demo'.this special access is called **closure**.

Comment: I don't think the OP is really asking about closure. He might wondering about the extra parenthesis in his second example.